# Get first N lines of output from a pipe operation

Tags: command-line, pipe, io-redirection, output

I'm using a piped command to migrate a big production DB from one host to another using this command:

`mysqldump <someparams> | pv | mysql <someparams>`

And I need to extract the line 23 (or let's say the first X lines) (saved as file or simply in bash output) from the SQL passing from one server to another.

**What I've tried:**

- Concatenate in output `less`, at least to see the output scrolling, but no luck

  `mysqldump <someparams> | pv | mysql <someparams> | less`
- Read about `sed`, but it's not useful to me
- Using head to write to a file, but it is empty

`mysqldump <someparams> | pv | mysql <someparams> | head -n 25 > somefile.txt`

The only requirement I have is that I cannot save this .sql file.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `zsh`

```
mysqldump <someparams> |
  pv > >(sed '22,24!d' > saved-lines-22-to-24.txt) |
  mysql <someparams>
```

With `bash` (or `zsh`):

```
mysqldump <someparams> |
  pv |
  tee >(sed '22,24!d' > saved-lines-22-to-24.txt) |
  mysql <someparams>
```

(though beware that as `bash` doesn't wait for that `sed` process, it's not guaranteed that `saved-lines-22-to-24.txt` will be complete by the time you run the next command in the script).

Or you could have `sed` to the writing:

```
mysqldump <someparams> |
  pv |
  sed '22,24 w saved-lines-22-to-24.txt' |
  mysql <someparams>
```

To have it as output, with `zsh`:

```
{mysqldump <someparams> |
  pv > >(sed '22,24!d' >&3) |
  mysql <someparams>} 3>&1
```

or `bash`/`zsh`:

```
{ mysqldump <someparams> |
  pv |
  tee >(sed '22,24!d' >&3)
  mysql <someparams>
} 3>&1
```

Comment: Worked perfeclty (I used the third solution you proposed me). Thank you sir!